# center mass of the solid

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the center mass of the solid bounded by planes $x+y+z=1,x=0,y=0$ and $z=0$, assuming a mass density of $$\rho(x,y,z) = 10 \sqrt{z}.$$

I could not set up the integral!

Comment: Typically,
$$
\text{mass} = \iiint_\Omega \rho(x,y,z) dV,
$$
where $\Omega$ denotes your region. Please provide some thoughts on the problem. We will be glad to furnish more hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mass of the volume is

$$M = \int_0^1 dx \, \int_0^{1-x} dy \, \int_0^{1-x-y} dz \, \rho$$

The $x$-coordinate of the COM is

$$\frac1{M} \int_0^1 dx\, x \, \int_0^{1-x} dy \, \int_0^{1-x-y} dz \, \rho$$

etc.

Comment: I need to find (x,y,z) so I get what you mean by that but i still did not get the way to find  those!

Comment: @user131040: Bill Cook's comment applies here as well, but what exactly do you think you are missing?  You did ask for the integral to be set up, and here we are.

Answer (score 4):

You can get bounds of integration by intersecting your various surfaces. For example: $x+y+z=1$ intersected with $z=0$ gives you $x+y+0=1$ so that $y=1-x$. Then intersect with $y=0$ and get $0=1-x$ so that $x=1$.

In the end, this region can be described as follows: $0 \leq z \leq 1-x-y$, $0 \leq y \leq 1-x$, $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

So to find the mass you'd need to integrate...
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} \int_0^{1-x-y} 10\sqrt{z}\,dz\,dy\,dx$$

Then the moment about the $yz$-plane is...
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} \int_0^{1-x-y} 10\sqrt{z} \cdot x\,dz\,dy\,dx$$

Comment: I need to find (x,y,z) so I get what you mean by that but i still did not get the way to find  those!

Comment: You already have what you need. I added the moment about the $yz$-plane above. That divided by the mass gives you the $x$-coordinate of the center of mass. You can get the $y$ and $z$ coordinates in a similar manner.